# Factory Boy subfactory over 'self'

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

Does anyone know how to create the factory in factoryboy based on this models.py

```
class Halte(models.Model):

    koppel_halte1 = models.ForeignKey('self',
                                  related_name='koppel_halteA',
                                  verbose_name="Koppel Halte",
                                  help_text="geef hier een gekoppelde halte aan",
                                  null=True, blank=True)

    koppel_halte2 = models.ForeignKey('self',
                                  related_name='koppel_halteB',
                                  verbose_name="Koppel Halte",
                                  help_text="geef hier een gekoppelde halte aan",
                                  null=True, blank=True)
```

Notice the 'self'? (And YES this type of relation is necesarry.)

I have tried several things in FactoryBoy (SubFactory, RelatedFactory, SelfAtribute, PostGeneration) but I can't get it to work.

one of the attempts in a factories.py

```
class HalteFactoryA(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Halte


class HalteFactoryB(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Halte


class HalteFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Halte
    # todo: how to do this?? (see models.Halte)
    koppel_halte1 = factory.RelatedFactory(HalteFactoryA)
    koppel_halte2 = factory.RelatedFactory(HalteFactoryB)
```

Any advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

@bakkal has it mostly right, but an important missing factor is that a target recursion depth must be specified, as stated in this issue:
https://github.com/rbarrois/factory_boy/issues/173

```
# myproj/myapp/factories.py
class MyModelFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
    parent = factory.SubFactory('myapp.factories.MyModelFactory')
```

Then a recursion max depth needs to be added, or you get the infinite depth reached error (as noted by @Sjoerd van Poelgeest in the comments):

```
m = MyModelFactory(parent__parent__parent__parent=None)
```

In This case we are allowing a depth of 3 being created, and the last one will have a null parent.

Answer (score 1):

### Fully qualified model name in the model FK

To make it easier on the tools to introspect your model, instead of `'self',` use the fully qualified model name:

```
koppel_halte1 = models.ForeignKey('yourapp.Halte', ...)
koppel_halte2 = models.ForeignKey('yourapp.Halte', ...)
```

Notice it's a string `'yourapp.Halte'` and not `yourapp.Halte`.

### Fully qualified *factory* name in the SubFactory

If you insist on using `'self'` in the model you can use the fully qualified model name in your `SubFactory`

```
# yourapp/factories.py

class HalteFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = yourapp.Halte

    koppel_halte1 = factory.SubFactory('yourapp.factories.HalteFactory')
    koppel_halte2 = factory.SubFactory('yourapp.factories.HalteFactory')
```

Comment: This might work, but how to create a factory boy instance from this. I'll update the question with a try of my own to clarify

Comment: I may have updated the answer before your comment, if you run into issues take note of the snippet and the error and we can discuss

Comment: hmm.. that just crashed all tests with a maximum recursion depth (infinite loop)...

I'm off for now. I'll try again next week.

Comment: Doing this alone will cause a maximum recursion depth error, according to this issue (https://github.com/rbarrois/factory_boy/issues/173), you need to create a cutoff  target depth.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to get it fixed with Factory Boy, but the old fashioned setup did work.

Then I'll (reluctantly) use the standard.

```
    class ModelHalteSelfTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.lijn1 = Lijn.objects.create(id=1, nummer=1, techniek=GlobalWaardes.TECHNIEK_BUS)
        self.lijn2 = Lijn.objects.create(id=2, nummer=2, techniek=GlobalWaardes.TECHNIEK_TRAM)

        self.halte1 = Halte.objects.create(id=1, nummer=100, aantal_vitrinekasten=2, aantal_hpkasten=0)
        self.halte2 = Halte.objects.create(id=2, nummer=200, aantal_vitrinekasten=1, aantal_hpkasten=1)
        self.halte3 = Halte.objects.create(id=3, nummer=300, aantal_vitrinekasten=0, aantal_hpkasten=3)
        self.halte4 = Halte.objects.create(id=4, koppel_halte1=self.halte1, koppel_halte2=self.halte2)

        self.halteregel1 = Halteregel.objects.create(id=1, lijn=self.lijn1, halte=self.halte1, volgorde=10)
        self.halteregel2 = Halteregel.objects.create(id=2, lijn=self.lijn1, halte=self.halte2, volgorde=20)
        self.halteregel3 = Halteregel.objects.create(id=3, lijn=self.lijn2, halte=self.halte2, volgorde=20)
        self.halteregel4 = Halteregel.objects.create(id=4, lijn=self.lijn2, halte=self.halte3, volgorde=10)

    def test_lijst_halteregels(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.halte1.lijst_halteregels(), [self.halteregel1])
        self.assertEqual(self.halte2.lijst_halteregels(), [self.halteregel2, self.halteregel3])
        self.assertEqual(self.halte3.lijst_halteregels(), [self.halteregel4])
        self.assertEqual(self.halte4.lijst_halteregels(), [self.halteregel1, self.halteregel2, self.halteregel3])
```